# How would I install portable virtual box to a USB drive to run on any Linux (Ubuntu) Host

Tags: virtualbox, software-installation, usb-drive

Looking for info on Google I can only find solutions to do it (install portable virtual box) on a Windows host, but I want it backward, I run Linux (Ubuntu) and I want to create a portable virtual machine to install Windows 8.1 on it(using virtual box) to carry on a flash drive.

How would I create a portable Windows 8.1 virtual machine using virtual box?

Comment: What do you mean "portable virtual machine"? You can copy the VM files to a flash drive. How much more portable can you get?

Comment: actually is not that simple, when you install vbox on a computer it runs according to that computer specific hardware. there is way of implementing a portable vbox on a windows host but i can't find a way for a linux host

Comment: You can do this  http://www.erikveen.dds.nl/qemupuppy/ with qemu puppy. comes with binaries for both linux and windows. you can, as suggested above. simply boot an alternate OS (you will have to make a virtual drive, insall, and modify the scripts and .bat files). Been too long since I did this, so can not give details.

Comment: home page - http://sourceforge.net/projects/qemupuppy/

Comment: The problem with portable virtual box is that it requires admin rights. If you have admin rights you install vbox and use a portable drive. If you wish, install vobx (and the dependencies) onto your flash drive, but you need to be running the same kernel on all linux hosts as vbox uses kernel modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do this with VirtualBox on Linux. The reason is that the VirtualBox installer copies specific files to the host system to configure it:

```
/lib/udev/rules.d/60-virtualbox.rules
/lib/udev/rules.d/60-virtualbox-dkms.rules
```

It also installs kernel modules on the host system:

```
/lib/modules/3.14-1-amd64/updates/dkms/vboxdrv.ko
/lib/modules/3.14-1-amd64/updates/dkms/vboxnetadp.ko
/lib/modules/3.14-1-amd64/updates/dkms/vboxnetflt.ko
/lib/modules/3.14-1-amd64/updates/dkms/vboxpci.ko
```

You need to do a proper install so that the host gets udev and the kernel modules that it requires in order to run VirtualBox.